# Creating landslide assessment with dynamic rainfall data using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to GEE and I am trying to create a landslide assessment which dynamically changes depending on the rainfall data from our source and shows the map on our website.

Currently, my processes are uploading all susceptibility maps which already processed using ArcGIS and calculate it, I can get the exact same result in GEE. However, since changes depend on the rainfall data, I would NOT want to calculate the rainfall data using IDW in ArcGIS and upload again to GEE just to get a new landslide map.

Is there a way to upload the rainfall data from our website and calculate the IDW in GEE together with other susceptibility maps so I could get a new landslide map?

Comment: It sounds like your question is "Can IDW be calculated using Google Earth Engine?"  If so, what has your research using those keywords uncovered?

Comment: Sorry if sounds confusing, I am aware we can IDW using GEE, but I have a source for rainfall data that needs to be uploaded automatically so I can do IDW to GEE

Comment: In that case it sounds like your question is "Can rainfall data be uploaded automatically to do IDW using Google Earth Engine?"  If so do you have code that enables you to do either step before you try to do them sequentially?

Comment: my plan was to have a function or method from our website to be able to upload the rainfall data to GEE then re-calculate with other susceptibility maps that will return a new landslide map. I just do not know the functions to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there, I ended up answering my own question. I successfully uploaded automatically from my local computer to GEE the rainfall data, do IDW and calculate with other do susceptibility maps. I followed the process from here: https://www.tucson.ars.ag.gov/notebooks/uploading_data_2_gee.html